# Include images saved on your computer in a question/answer

Tags: feature-request, images

Is it possible to include images, such as .gif, .jpg or .jpeg-files one has saved on one's computer in a question or an answer to a question? If so, how? I checked the "Markdown Editing Help"-section of this website but it seems to me that only images that are on the web are mentioned.

Thanks,

Max

Comment: See the section on "Images" near the end of the markdown help which begins:  "Images are exactly like links, but they have an exclamation point in front of them:"

Comment: See http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/21341/how-do-i-upload-an-image-for-use-in-a-question and http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13340/step-by-step-solution-to-upload-a-png-image-from-my-desktop-named-snap

Answer (score 8):

Yes. When asking or answering a question, note that there are buttons above the text box; click the sixth one from the left, and you should have a dialog box for uploading pictures.

Comment: @ J.M. woops there they are... how could I have over-looked these buttons?! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Also, while this doesn't apply to Max anymore, there is a very minimal minimum rep threshold for including images in a post. (10)